# Disable download/print button in primefaces documentViewer

Tags: primefaces, pdf.js, primefaces-extensions

I want to disable download and print button in the documentViewer's toolbar
I tried to do it in JavaScript and CSS as shown below, but but neither worked.

Any suggestions?

I tried to do it like this (JavaScript):

```
$(function() {
    $('#download').hide();
});
```

And in CSS like this:

```
.download {
    display:none !important;    
}

.print {
    display:none !important;
}
```

My XHTML implementation

```
<h:form id="ReportViewerForm">  
        <f:event listener="#{ReportController.printReportSchedule}" type="preRenderView" />
             <p:panel id="ReportViewerPanel" header="" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <pe:documentViewer height="500" value="#{ReportController.content}"/> 
            </p:panel>   
</h:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `rendered` attribute in the component itself?

Comment: as far as i know it doesn't have a rendered attribute

Comment: Can you show the actual code of the component you are using please?

Comment: ok, i added my xhtml implementation in the question

Comment: Seeking in the code at: [documentViewer js code](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/documentviewer/pdf.viewer.js) There is an object that you may use to hide it: See the line 20502 where the object is been set then look at the line 20584. You may take advantage on those objects. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
#download {
    display:none !important;    
}
```

Works for me in PrimeFaces 6.0 (note the # instead of the .) (without the !important it works to btw)

Answer (score 0):

DocumentViewer can not be modified by adding and forcing css or javascript.
DocumentViewer runs inside a JFrame which does not allow inserting css and javascript.
The most optimal solution and the one that worked for me is the following:

1. Extract the jar file of primefaces "primefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar" with zip

[image]

2. Edit the file \ META-INF \ resources \ primefaces-extensions \ documentviewer \ viewer.html and add style = "display: none;"

   Print

   Download
3. Save and re-compress it with the extension jar "primefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar"
4. Replace the jar file and deploy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can force CSS config using a remoteCommand with autoRun = "true". Call the javascript from the oncomplete. That works.

Answer (score 0):

The pdfview is in an iFrame.  So you have to apply the css changes to it directly.

```
<pe:documentViewer url="#{pdfcontroller.pdfPath}" id="pdfVw" />
```

Then I used javasript to run on ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pdfVw').contents().find('#download').css('display', 'none');
    $('#pdfVw').contents().find('#print').css('display', 'none');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer based on Javascript on primefaces forum and it worked for me 
this is the link https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=55587

1. Add this method to your application javascript file.

   ```
   pdfHideButton : function(button) {
   $('iframe').on('load',
           function() {
               var head = $(this).contents().find('head');
               var css = '<style type="text/css">#' + button   + '{display:none};</style>';
               $(head).append(css);
           });}
   ```
2. On your page with the PDF Viewer you can do this to hide the OpenFile and BookMark buttons...

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>       $(document).ready(function() {
>               pdfHideButton('download');
>                 pdfHideButton('viewBookmark');
>           });
>       </script>
> ```